# highcharts graph with one regular column and one stacked column

Tags: highcharts

How do I achieve this with highcharts? I need to have one column in green, and 1 stacked column with red and orange.

No other series. Just one with these 2 columns.

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far, any code to share ?

Comment: I don't know how to begin

Comment: Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use individual color for every point:

```
  series: [{
    data: [{
      y: 1,
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      y: 2,
      color: 'red'
    }]
  }, {
    data: [{
      y: 3,
      color: 'orange'
    }]
  }]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/cdfyo3y1/

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.color